# Specializing class for generic function returning pointer to function

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to specialize a class template declared as such:

```
template<typename T> class A;
```

for a function returning a function pointer. This needs to be a generic signature for any given arity of function.

So, assuming that I know how C/C++ syntax works, the specialization should look something like this for a function returning some type `ResultType`:

```
template<typename ResultType, typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
A<ResultType(Arg1, Arg2)> {...};
```

And expanding that to having ResultType being a function pointer should look something like this:

```
template<typename FpResultType, typename FpArg1, typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
A<(ResultType(*)(FpArg1))(Arg1, Arg2)> {...};
```

This, however, results in an 'invalid template parameter' on GCC 4.6.

As far as I know typedefs are a no-go here. Adding a utility class to create a typedef for me is additionally a no-go, as that moves types from the list of typenames in the template declaration to within another template type and 'hides' them from A's template specialization (resulting in a compile-time error that the typenames declared are not used in the specialization).

I'd rather like to avoid having a long complex chain of enable_ifs and utility structs. But, if that's the only way to do it, meh.

Comment: What's the signature of the function pointer you want to return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will work if you specialize it as:

```
template<typename FpResultType, typename FpArg1, typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
A<ResultType (*(Arg1, Arg2))(FpArg1)> {...};
```

I tested with the following code, which compiles successfully (using Clang):

```
template<typename T> class A;

template<typename FnRetT, typename FnArgT, typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
class A<FnRetT (*(Arg1, Arg2))(FnArgT)>
{
public:
  typedef FnRetT fn_ret_t;
};

float foo(float a)
{
  return a;
}

float (*getfn(int arg1, int arg2))(float)
{
  return foo;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  typedef A<decltype(getfn)>::fn_ret_t ret_ty;

  return 0;
}
```

Note that the syntax used to match the function type matches the declaration of `getfn`.

Comment: Much gracias senor. May the Spanish inquisition not try to get me for slaughtering their language in this comment and abusing templates with the tools given here.